# I don't know how to get rid of this grid

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I am trying to make bones for my character but when I use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in edit mode I get a mesh displayed. Earlier I could make an armature bone, but now I cannot. Here is how it looks now:

[image: black grid]

I would like to know how to get to normal faze like I had it before this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're in **Edit Mode**. In *Edit Mode* you can only edit data of an object (in this case your mesh).

Go into **Object Mode** by pressing the TAB key.

Comment: omg... i feel so stupid right now :), thank you VERY much for that.

Comment: If it helped, please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted.